# EU Python hosting

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for Python hosting in EU. I need WSGI support (nginx+uwsgi, apache+mod_wsgi or similar). What are the options, excluding VPS/dedicated server?

Answer (score 1):

[WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/services/hosting) offer Python–several versions of mod_wsgi–and you can choose in Amsterdam. They run Apache normally, but you can [set up nginx yourself](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/install-nginx-webfaction/) if you really want it. It's shared hosting, but you have near-VPS access to do such things; it comes in handy.

Comment: I read about 80Mb memory limit. Is that for 1 application or for all application you host with 1 package?

Comment: Did you also read the footnote about it? It works a bit differently than you might think(basically it sounds a lot lower than the reality). Honestly, though, I've never had to run into it, so can only tell you so much. If it's of particular concern, you should probably use the live chat(in the top nav) and someone there can give you specifics.